# How to call a public function form other component?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I have two component A and B.
and A have a public function which is 'function_A()'.

how do I call it form B without making it to a static function??

Comment: I find out only need to declare the comp and all its method can be used.

var a:A;
a.function_A();

very easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A component instance is basically an object. So you should always let components interact with each other how the various OOP paradigms suggest objects should interact.

As for view components: avoid as much interaction as possible and try to implement your application via MV* (MVC, MVP, MVVM, ...) pattern. This appears to be more complicated at first. But these design approaches scale with the size and live span of a project. Letting objects know and do too much, not.